Only write over data to csv line without losing previous data?
I have a starting csv with sample data like so:
Underlying,AllBlue,AllRed
AUD,1/5/2024,
BRR,,
GBP, 3/10/2024,
CAD,,


Today, 2024/04/29,  via another process, a new CSV is produced, like this for example
Underlying,AllBlue,AllRed
AUD,,
BRR,4/29/2024,
GBP,4/29/2024,
CAD,,4/29/2024

and I'm looking to append any  new data found in columns 'AllBlue' and 'AllRed' only, to the original csv.
Desired outcome would be
Underlying,AllBlue,AllRed
AUD,1/5/2024,
BRR ,4/29/2024,
GBP,4/29/2024,
CAD,,4/29/2024

Notice how the new data from 2024/04/29 csv is overwriting to original.  Also, how the GBP/AllBlue cell is updated with the new date.

#sandbox testing
$CSVFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Sandbox\test" -Filter "*.csv"
 
#put into array
$CSVData = @()

ForEach ($CSVFile in $CSVFiles) {
    $CSVContent = Import-Csv -Path $CSVFile.FullName 
    $CSVData += $CSVContent 
}
 
#output
$CSVData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Sandbox\testoutput\colors.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append


This is what I'm currently getting back though.
"Underlying","AllBlue","AllRed"
"AUD","1/5/2024",""
"BRR","",""
"GBP","3/10/2024",""
"CAD","",""
"AUD","",""
"BRR","4/29/2024",""
"GBP","4/29/2024",""
"CAD","","4/29/2024"

This appends the data, but doesn't overwrite the columns?. I've tried multiple parameters clobber, append.

Is there any coding attempt you have tried already? and if so, please add it to your question

The data you have submitted is not the content of any CSV files. You appear to have tried to replicate how they are displayed in a particular application instead of opening them in a plain text editor, then copying and pasting it here. Please replace those when you [Edit] your question to include your code and debugging information.

Please edit the question and copy/paste the output of Get-Content -Path 'thefile.csv' as text. No pictures.

question: what EXACTLY does the NEW CSV contains? does it contains all lines of the original but with SOME different values? Does it contains SOME lines of the original with SOME different values?

This is one way you can get that desired output. Inline comments should help with the thought process.
# Import-Csv here instead
$sourceCsv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Underlying,AllBlue,AllRed
AUD,1/5/2024,
BRR,,
GBP, 3/10/2024,
CAD,,
'@

# Import-Csv here instead
$newCsv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Underlying,AllBlue,AllRed
AUD,,
BRR,4/29/2024,
GBP,4/29/2024,
CAD,,4/29/2024
ThisIsALineToAppend,,4/29/2024
'@

# create a hashtable using the Underlying property as keys
$map = $sourceCsv | Group-Object Underlying -AsHashTable

$linesToAppend = foreach ($line in $newCsv) {
    # if the Underlying value of the new Csv exists in the old CSV
    if ($map.ContainsKey($line.Underlying)) {
        # get the object having the same Underlying value of the old CSV
        $value = $map[$line.Underlying][0]
        # if the AllBlue of the new CSV is not null
        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line.AllBlue)) {
            # update the object of the old CSV with this new value
            $value.AllBlue = $line.AllBlue
        }
        # if the AllRed of the new CSV is not null
        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line.AllRed)) {
            # update the object of the old CSV with this new value
            $value.AllRed = $line.AllRed
        }

        # go to the next iteration
        continue
    }

    # else, this Underlying doesn't exist in the old CSV
    # so its gotta be appended
    $line
}

$sourceCsv + $linesToAppend | ConvertTo-Csv


This is working as expected.  Thanks a lot for commenting the script lines Santiago. This helps tremendously.

@iceman glad it was helpful. remember if it solves your issue you can accept the answer

This expands on the answer by @Santiago. This will allow multiple fields to make up a compound key for each row. It will also compare all of the non-key fields without requiring them to be hardcoded. It is not difficult if there are two (2) fields to compare. It is a lot more troublesome if there are eighty-two (82) fields to compare.
$NaturalKey = @('Underlying','New')

# Import-Csv here instead
$sourceCsv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Underlying,New,AllBlue,AllRed
AUD,9,1/5/2024,
BRR,8,,
GBP,7, 3/10/2024,
CAD,6,,
'@

# Import-Csv here instead
$newCsv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Underlying,New,AllBlue,AllRed
AUD,9,,
BRR,8,4/29/2024,
GBP,7,4/29/2024,
CAD,6,,4/29/2024
ThisIsALineToAppend,5,,4/29/2024
'@

# Compare the fields of both CSV files to ensure that they have the names.
# The fields do not need to be in the same order.
$SourceFields = $sourceCsv[0].psobject.Properties.name | Sort-Object
$NewFields = $newCsv[0].psobject.Properties.name | Sort-Object
if ($null -ne (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceFields -DifferenceObject $NewFields)) {
    Write-Error -Message 'CSV files do not have the same field names or number of fields."'
    return 1
}
# Only test for new values in the fields that are not part of the natural key.
$FieldsToCompare = foreach ($Field in $NewFields) { if ($Field -notin $NaturalKey) { $Field }}

# create a hashtable using the Underlying property as keys
$map = $sourceCsv | Group-Object $NaturalKey -AsHashTable -AsString

# Iterate over all rows of the new CSV file.
$linesToAppend = foreach ($line in $newCsv) {
    # Gather the fields comprising the natural key.
    $KeyValues = foreach ($k in $NaturalKey) { $line.$k }
    $Key = $KeyValues -join ', '
    # if the natural key value of the new Csv exists in the old CSV
    if ($map.ContainsKey($Key)) {
        # get the object having the same Underlying value of the old CSV
        $value = $map[$Key][0]
        # Iterate over the fields to be compared (all fields except those in the natural key).
        foreach ($Field in $FieldsToCompare) {
            # If the new field valus is not null or whitespace, replace the existing value.
            if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line.$Field)) {
                $value.$Field = $line.$Field
            }
        }
    } else {
        # else, this Underlying doesn't exist in the old CSV
        # so its gotta be appended
        $line
    }
}

$sourceCsv + $linesToAppend | ConvertTo-Csv

